# How do I account for daylight savings time when retrieving current time in PHP?

Tags: php, time, dst

When getting the time via PHP script (**`time()`**), during Daylight Savings Time it seems to return a time value that is one hour off. Is there any way to get the correct time, accounting for Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: See: [Simple PHP timezone / daylight saving question](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=223035.0)

Comment: You can get PHP's timezone setting with `date('e')` and/or `date_default_timezone_get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time()` returns a Unix timestamp and a Unix timestamp is a fixed period of time: number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. It isn't affected by time zones.

Once you have the precise moment, you may want to calculate the local time in a given place:

```
<?php

$now = time();
echo $now . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
echo date('r', $now) . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo date('r', $now) . PHP_EOL;
```

... will print different local dates for the same timestamp:

```
1313683738
Thu, 18 Aug 2011 18:08:58 +0200
Fri, 19 Aug 2011 01:08:58 +0900
```

The same reasoning applies for the opposite operation:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$then = mktime(23, 55, 30, 12, 31, 2000);
echo $then . PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$then = mktime(23, 55, 30, 12, 31, 2000);
echo $then . PHP_EOL;
```

... will print different timestamps:

```
978303330
978274530
```

Answer (score 0):

time() gets the OS time in Unix Timestamp format. You could correct this with PHP but imho this should be something to consider fixing on OS level.

Answer (score 0):

Either make sure the system time is current, or add/subtract in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#69221

Comment: I'd like to add that the date function has a specific flag for daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

Set correct timezone using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Or set the timezone via php.ini in PHP<5

Answer (score 0):

This won't be "the" answer, but the local server time can be mismanaged by your provider.  I don't know the context for your use of the time information, but whenever I use such information, I attempt to use UTD/GMT.  If your users are spread out over the world, or even a single country, rectifying time can be a nightmare.  Representing things, like file save times, log times, or other uses can be done reasonably with UDT/GMT.

Comment: What's UTD/GMT time or UDT/GMT time? Maybe you mean UTC/GMT time or is it something else?